# APK Debug vs APK Realease. No consume webservice, no funciona operaciones base de datos

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo un problema.
Tengo mi app móvil en android studio. El APK generado en modo DEBUG funciona correctamente consumiendo servicios web y realizando operaciones sobre la base de datos local en android. Todos los permisos están correctamente configurados. Pero cuando se genera el APK Release no funciona el consumo de lo servicios web y las operaciones sobre la base de datos. No he podido detectar el problema. Alquien que pueda ayudarme?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuando haces en release también se conecta a la base de datos local?

Answer (score 1):

Esto no debería ser problema de la firma,

> La firma de tu .APK es necesaria para ser identificada como una
>   aplicación para la PlayStore, pero no modifica los permisos o el funcionamiento de tu aplicación.

Definitivamente el problema debe ser otro, te sugiero por experiencia revisar los url del Web Service cuando firmas tu aplicación a producción, así como las credenciales que requiere.

Comment: No es un problema de urls porque así como genero el apk en modo debug lo genero en modo release. No hago ningún cambio. Solamente genero el release y ya. :(

Comment: Al probar tu aplicación la pruebas en un dispositivo real, antes de firmarla para la playstore? podrías agregar un poco de código de tu consulta al WS?

Answer (score 0):

Hola ya probaste agregando al manifiest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />
```

también pon en false la opción de optimización en el buildtypes:

```
  buildTypes {
    release {
    minifyEnabled true
    useProguard false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }

  debug {
     applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
  }
}
```